# Heroku: Error R99 (Platform error) when running `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, heroku, rake

I am running a Heroku app under multiple environments as described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments). I am able to run under my original single environment fine, but when I push to one of the others and run `heroku run rake db:migrate --remote REMOTE_NAME` I get an error of the form `Error: Operation timed out - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)`.

The `heroku logs` output for this instance is as follows:

```
heroku[api]: Starting process with command `rake db:migrate`
heroku[run.9488]: Awaiting client
heroku[run.9488]: Starting process with command `rake db:migrate`
heroku[run.9488]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Failed to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
heroku[run.9488]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
heroku[run.9488]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
heroku[run.9488]: Process exited with status 128
heroku[run.9488]: State changed from starting to complete
```

What is the correct process for migrating a database when working with multiple deployment environments?

Comment: R99 Platform errors are not application errors. If you're experiencing this right now I would open a support ticket at help.heroku.com